# Modified central difference formula

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Prove or disprove the assertion: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then for $\alpha \neq 1$ 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x+ \alpha h)}{h- \alpha h} = f'(x)
\end{equation}
I first attempted to prove this with a Taylor expansion, but I don't know any information about $f''(x)$. I tried to use the definition of derivative, but the resulting absolute value expressions don't seem helpful.

Comment: Is l'Hospital's rule applicable?  I would say yes, under the assumption that $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: anything about $\alpha$??

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You may just use the differentiability of $f$ at $x$, by writing, **as $h \to 0$**:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x+ \alpha h)}{h- \alpha h} &= \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\frac{f(x)-f(x+ \alpha h)}{h}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x+ \alpha h)}{\alpha h}\right)\\\\
& \longrightarrow \frac{1}{1-\alpha}f'(x)-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}f'(x)=\color{red}{f'(x)}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x+\alpha h\right)}{h-\alpha h}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\frac{f\left(x+\alpha h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{\alpha h}$$

If $h\rightarrow0$ then this expression converges to: $$\frac{1}{1-\alpha}f'\left(x\right)-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}f'\left(x\right)=f'\left(x\right)$$